# Update field using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to update my lead_status it's not updating it's only redirecting to a page but can't update my lead status and when I return or dd($leads) it gives 0. why let me where I'm wrong and suggest me a solution

**my update query**

```
public function leadUpdate(Request $request)
{

    $ids = $request->ids;
    $lead_status = $request->lead_status;

    $leads = DB::table('leads')
            ->where('id', $ids)
            ->update(['lead_status' => $lead_status]);
            

    
    dd($leads);

    return redirect('home/progress-leads')->with('success', 'lead accepted successfully');
  
}
```

**my route is**

```
Route::put('/home/accept-leads','HomeController@leadUpdate');
```

**my blade form is**

```
        <form action="{{ url('home/accept-leads') }}" method="POST">
            
            @csrf
            @method('PUT')
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Accept Leads</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
                            <h3>Are you sure to accept this lead</h3>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="ids" value="{{ $leads->id }}">   
                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="lead_status">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
            </div>
            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button formaction="/home/accept-leads" type="submit" onclick="return myConfirm();" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Please help me...
Thanks in advance

Comment: if they don't check that checkbox then there won't be an 'ids' input passed

Comment: oh...I'm sorry sir...It was my silly fault. Now it's working....Thanks for your response